# How to find the acme challenge response?

Tags: django, lets-encrypt, certbot, acme

I'm using a [django-letsencrypt](https://github.com/urda/django-letsencrypt) and it requires me to enter in the acme challenge and the acme challenge response. I'm able to find the challenge but I'm not able to find the proper response to use. Where can I find the response? I'm using acme V2